# htacess Proxy Redirect /a to /b, 301 redirect of /b to /a

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have website built on a bespoke centralised legacy CMS.

It has a section which works under the URL /database

For one site I'd like to change that to use /blog and it still needs to tell the CMS that it's database.

So for .htaccess I have

```
RewriteRule ^blog$ /database [P,L]
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ /database/$1 [P,L]
```

Which works great. But I also need to tell google that the site has changed and not to look at the old one.

So I need /database to 301 to /blog.

So:

```
RewriteRule ^database$ /blog [L,R=301]
```

I've tested this with http://htaccess.madewithlove.be and it says it's fine, but it's causing an infinite loop in the browser.

To be honest I feel like part of the problem is that I can't really express the question very well, especially the title, so any feedback on that would be appreciated.

Here's the rest of the file just in case that's relevant

```
# redirect trailing slashes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.+)?fromMobile=true$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /$1?%1&%2 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

#uk.com
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^iflg\.uk\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.iflg.uk.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^blog$ /database [P,L]
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ /database/$1 [P,L]

#RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=localhost
#RewriteRule ^database$ /blog [L,R=301]

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php
</IfModule>


<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /~iflg/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /~iflg/index.php
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to exempt the second rule to prevent the proxy server from being redirected too.

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=127.0.0.1
RewriteRule ^database$ /blog [L,R=301]
```

Do not rely on that htaccess tester, it is too simplistic.

Comment: Thanks for this, it makes sense, but it doesn't work for me. I've added my full htaccess incase there's anything else in there that's relevant. i checked with ifconfig and the server does identify as 127.0.0.1 and I tried localhost instead and that didn't work either